# Document.write issues

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a page where users can answer questions (using radio buttons) about a product they are selling back. When they hit a button at the bottom of the page, a price quote will pop up. I have written a javascript function to be performed when the user hits the button. It calculates the price and displays it using document.write, but whenever the user hits the button, it opens up a new page and displays what I told it to.

```
function getQuote(){
    document.write("Your Quote Is: $", price, ".00");
}
```

And here is the code for the button:

```
<button type="button" onclick='getQuote()'>Display Quote</button>
```

But when I push the button, a new page shows up and it shows the quote with only the formatting I put into the `document.write` phrase.

I have tried using `.innerHTML` to send the `document.write` to another part of the page, but the same problem persists.

What can I do to make sure that the quote shows up on the page, where I want it to?

Comment: If you call `document.write` after the DOM is built, it erases the whole content. I suggest you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: How are you getting the price variable? It looks like price is not displaying perhaps because it is not defined properly. Have you tried firebugging it and checking for javascript bugs? http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Matthew. Be prepared to put the SO bookmark where the facebook, gmail or twitter one was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no** issue with `document.write`, it is doing exactly what it is supposed to do:

> Overwrite the page with the new content.

If you **do not** want to do that, then you have to give it some context to write to.

For example:

```
function getQuote(){
    var textArea = document.getElementById('textArea');
    textArea.innerHTML = "Your Quote Is: $", price, ".00";
}
```

Which puts whatever your text is into a DOM element with `id="textArea"`

Answer (score 2):

After your document has been full rendered and closed, using `document.write()` will clear your current document and start a new one, wiping out all previous content.

The put content into the existing document you need to use DOM manipulation functions, not `document.write()`.  If, what you're trying to do is to change the text of your button, you can do so like this (assuming `price` is a global variable that contains the price):

```
<button type="button" onclick='getQuote(this)'>Display Quote</button>

function getQuote(obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = "Your Quote Is: $" + price + ".00";
}
```

If you want to put the price into some other object on the page, then you give that object an id and you can get that object and set the price into it like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick='getQuote()'>Display Quote</button>
<div id="quotedPrice"></div>

function getQuote() {        
    document.getElementById("quotedPrice").innerHTML = "Your Quote Is: $" + price + ".00";    
}
```

You can see both forums of these work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ED5V9/

Answer (score 1):

You should reference the element, and set its content instead of using `document.write`.

```
<button type="button" onclick='getQuote.call(this)'>Display Quote</button>
```

---

```
function getQuote(){
     this.firstChild.data = "Your Quote Is: $" + price + ".00";
}
```

---

If you want to write to a different element, you should select that element, and likely use the same technique.