# How do you add a input element to a variable

Tags: javascript

I input a number into a textbox.

I want to know how do you cast this number to a declared variable:

For Example:

```
<body>
Please Enter value number 1: <input type = "text" id = "value1"></input>&nbsp;
<button onclick = "Display()">Display</button>
<p id = "Paragraph"></p>

<script>
```

The Question is here:

```
var a = document.getElementById("value1").value;
```

The statement above is what i want to know to do.

```
function Display()
{
document.write(a);
}
</script>
</body>
```

I am new to javascript, and i'm trying to learn so sorry if the question is a bit basic but im struggling to get this right.

Comment: What is not working? What do you expect?

Comment: the variable that i declared (var a) when written to the page does not display anything.

Comment: Try removing `</input>`: `function Display(){ document.write(document.getElementById('value1').value); }`

Comment: exact duplicate of [Document.write issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648365/document-write-issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this:

```
function Display()
{
  var a = document.getElementById("value1").value;

  document.getElementById( 'Paragraph' ).innerHTML = a;
}
```

With your code the variable `a` is just assigned, when the script is executed the *first* time. It is not a pointer to the value, but just grabs the value once. So if you want to use it, when clicking the button, you have to get it inside the executed function.

<sub>Don't use `document.write()` like this. If you want to display something at runtime [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) is a better choice!</sub>

Comment: Why not pass `this` into the function and then traverse with `previousSibling` to the input element? Why query the entire page when the button and input are siblings?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Judging from the level of experience shown in the code of OP, I guess this is the far more obvious reason. Furthermore, I don't like to rely on structural information (which may change quite easily), when I don't have to. Finally, getting elements by ID is quite cheap wrt performance, so nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 4):

Assign `a` inside your function:

```
function Display()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    console.log(a);
}
```

Also, `<input />` tags do not require a closing `</input>` tag.

Comment: Nor do should they have a `/` before the closing `>` in the tag, unless you are writing XHTML.